# Why am I all of a sudden getting errors from Sourceforge in my Maven project?

Tags: maven, sourceforge

I have suddenly started getting errors in my Maven project similar to the one shown below.  I am even getting these errors in older releases of my project that used to build with out error.  Why are these errors suddenly happening now? Should I be expecting more errors like this in the future? Is there a place I can find out about the changes that are causing these error before I'm exposed to them? I'm currently running Java 1.7 (updating to 1.8 is not an option).

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myprojcore: Could not resolve dependencies for project myorg-myproj:myprojcore:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT: 
        Failed to collect dependencies for [myorg-myproj:myprojrestclient:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
        myorg-myproj:myprojgfclient:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), myorg-myproj:myprojjbossclient:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT 
        (compile), myorg-myproj:myorgserver:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), myorg-myproj:common:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT 
        (compile), myorg-myproj:myorgmessage:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), myorg-myproj:dag:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
        myorg-myproj:graph:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), myorg-myproj:fhirdata:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
        xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1 (compile), myorg-myproj:ojdbc6:jar:4.1 (system), com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0 
        (compile), mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.24 (runtime), xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.7 (test)]: 
        Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0: 
        Could not transfer artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc:sqljdbc4:pom:4.0 from/to myorg-myproj.repo 
        (https://myorg-myproj.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/myorg-myproj/repos/repo): com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: 
        PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; 
        internal cause is:
[ERROR] java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=DST Root CA X3, 
        O=Digital Signature Trust Co. is not trusted; internal cause is:
[ERROR] java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not an SSH error. Maven is trying to access https://myorg-myproj.svn.sourceforge.net/, and it's getting an error validating the certificate for that page.

According to twitter, Sourceforge is having problems right now:

https://twitter.com/sfnet_ops/status/913044025791467520

SourceForge is experiencing connectivity issues. We are working with our upstream provider.— SF.net Operations (@sfnet_ops) [September 27, 2017](https://twitter.com/sfnet_ops/status/913044025791467520)

Comment: I removed the sourceforge dependency from the project an it's working now.  Thanks.